# A.0.1 figure labels in Appendix

Tags: floats, numbering, appendices

I have two issues:

1. The figures/tables in my appendix
   are being labeled `A.0.1` instead of
   `A.1`.  I assume this is because of the
   convention in my document is
   `chapter.section.#`. How do I change
   this for the appendix only?
2. My bibliography is being considered at a higher level than the appendices and it's noticeable in the ToC and the pdf `hyperref` structure.

See [my example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5962491/lyx__example.zip) (Contains LyX document and `.tex` export)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the tip.  Any thoughts on why the bibliography is "including" the appendix?  The page number of the bibliography in the TOC is better than any other page numbers and when you look at the bookmarks, you have to open Bibliography to see the appendices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the line `\numberwithin{figure}{Chapter}` to `\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}` (chapter without capital C) and it should be fine.

Comment: To clarify for newbies such as myself, the "line" should be inserted just after the first appendix header (so that only from that point forth it is changed). If you are using LyX you can do so with ERT just after the heading.